# How do I embed meta data in a non-standard file?

Tags: c#, metadata, visual-studio-2019

I need to write code that receives firmware update files from various sources (nothing is a given, not even the file extensions) and passes them up to the cloud so that our software can download them to individual machines.

As part of the process, the front end needs to give the users a richer experience, so I need to include information such as the version number, last time there was an approved update to the file, and some other info about who is responsible for the update.

I've been directed to pass the data in as "meta-data" so that we don't have to include two files and at this point that doesn't seem like a very viable option.  I've been researching meta data all day.  TagLib is only for media files.  I can use Microsoft API Code Pack to read some attributes but it won't let me write anything.

The shell32 option looks like the only other possibility but I can't figure out how to write to it.  I'm using C# code in VS 2019, currently .NET framework 4.6.1 but we are about to upgrade to 4.8, I think.

Is there a practical way to write a string value as meta-data into a file without knowing anything more about the file than what I could discover with c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to provide additional files or locations with the meta information you can create a new single file which contains your meta data and the actual firmware update. Think of it as a ZIP file where you have the firmware update file and some other file with the meta information. This way you will have only one file you can send around, but it has all the information you will need at any later point.

You cannot change the firmware update file in any way, specially if you don't know how the file format is. It would most likely break the firmware update.

Comment: Not sure what you try to do, but using e.g. an XML file for your additional data and wrap it all in a .zip files seems a viable solution. At the client side reading dat from a zip file is not very difficult..NET offers all you ned for this purpose. Also .NET offers features to build zip files.  Nb metadata is just data and can be treted like any data.